# problem in httpdelete request asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

Hello i am working on asp.net core 2.2 web api , my get request is working fine but i am having problem in HTTPDELETE request, my code for the delete request is as follows

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PatientController : ControllerBase
{
    IPatientManager _patientManager;
    IEnumerable<Patient> patientList;

    public PatientController(IPatientManager patientManager)
    {
        _patientManager = patientManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Patient> Get()
    {
        return (patientList = _patientManager.GetAllPatients());
    }


    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("api/Patient/{id}")]
    public bool Delete(long id)
    {
        if (_patientManager.DeletePatient(id))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

}

when i put the request in URL as localhost:3, n922/api/Patient/444373 it gives me HTTP ERROR 404 , my startup.cs file is using the below code for MapRoute

```
 app.UseMvc(opt =>
            {
                opt.MapRoute("Default",
                    "{controller=Patient}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
            });
```

to start the my PatientController instead of ValuesController, Please help what is problem where i am doing wrong? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You have a route prefix defined on your controller as `api/[controller]`, which translates to `/api/Patient`. Then, your route on your action is defined as `api/Patient/{id}`, which makes the entire route to this action: `/api/Patient/api/Patient/{id}`. That's obviously not right and is the source of your 404. Change the route to just `{id}`.

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public bool Delete(long id)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me either when i put the request as /api/patient/5 it gives me 405 error :( in the browser